# Can't see older kernels in GRUB menu

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I have a problem with my microphone and webcam. A colleague suggested that I should revert my kernel to version `5.3.0-40-generic`, while currently I'm using `5.3.0-46-generic`. 
The problem is, when I open the GRUB menu and want to select which kernel I use, I only see

```
5.3.0-46-generic
5.3.0-46-generic safe-mode
5.3.0-45-generic
5.3.0-45-generic safe-mode
```

I think that I do have `5.3.0-40-generic` on my system, as my output of `dpkg --list | grep linux-image` is:

```
rc  linux-image-5.0.0-23-generic                 5.0.0-23.24~18.04.1                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.3.0-26-generic                 5.3.0-26.28~18.04.1                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.3.0-28-generic                 5.3.0-28.30~18.04.1                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.3.0-40-generic                 5.3.0-40.32~18.04.1                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.3.0-42-generic                 5.3.0-42.34~18.04.1                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.3.0-45-generic                 5.3.0-45.37~18.04.1                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.3.0-46-generic                 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04                5.3.0.46.102                                     amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

Does anyone have an idea of how I can get the older kernel versions shown in the GRUB, so that I can select (and later default) the `5.3.0-40-generic` version?

I'm a bit new at Ubuntu, so steps and tips are appreciated!

Comment: The 'ii' in the first column show installed kernels, the 'rc' ones are available  but were removed (during clean)

Comment: You can find the kernel and headers here. https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.1.40/  this version is according to package search not longer available in normal sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only `linux-image-5.3.0-45-generic` and `linux-image-5.3.0-46-generic` are currently installed on your system. If you need an older kernel version, you'll have to install them via `apt`.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to install them! Unfortunately it did not fix my underlying problem, but my question here is solved.